# How to clear a single bit in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I did it like that: [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c).

> **Clearing a bit**
>
> Use the bitwise AND operator (`&`) to clear a bit.
>
> number &= ~(1 << x);
>
> That will clear bit `x`. You must invert the bit string with the
>   bitwise NOT operator (`~`), then AND it.

It works fine with signed integer types, but doesn't work with unsigned integer (e.g. UInt32). Compiler says that it's impossible to do that kind of operation to unsigned types. How to deal with unsigned numbers to clear one bit then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't actually say that. It says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

That's because `1 << x` will be of type `int`.

Try `1u << x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UInt32 number = 40;
Int32 x = 5;
number &= ~((UInt32)1 << x);
```

Comment: Yes, the shifter has to be signed, the shiftee can be unsigned. And `(UInt32)1` can be written `1U`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the result, which is a `long`, back to a `uint` if you replace the compound operator `&=` with a normal `&`:

```
uint number = /*...*/;
number = (uint)(number & ~(1 << x));
```

Another way would be to use the `unchecked` block:

```
uint number = /*...*/;
unchecked
{
    number &= (uint)~(1 << x);
}
```

Comment: No (intermediate) result is `long`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: `(number & ~(1 << x)).GetType()` is `System.Int64`

Comment: To my surprise, yes. But `(number & ~(1U << x)).GetType()` is `System.Int32`

Answer (score 0):

Bit manipulation can be done for multiple types using the generic math interfaces defined since .NET7 (C# 11): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math.

Clearing a bit:

```cs
public static T ClearBit<T>(this T value, int bitNumber) where T :
    IBinaryNumber<T>,
    IShiftOperators<T, int, T>
{
    T mask = T.One << bitNumber;
    return value & ~mask;
}
```

And setting a bit:

```cs
public static T SetBit<T>(this T value, int bitNumber) where T : 
    IBinaryNumber<T>, 
    IShiftOperators<T, int, T>
{
    T mask = T.One << bitNumber;
    return value | mask;
}
```

The generic interfaces `IBinaryNumber<T>` and `IShiftOperators<T, int, T>` are defined for: byte, int, uint, long, ulong, etc.